# MySQL having SUM(column1) <> column2 does not work

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions, having

I'm working on a query that uses having to compare a sum of elements from a joined table to a value of a field from the "main" table.
Here's the gist of my query:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id -- AND OTHER CONDITIONS
-- WHERE more t1 conditions
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING SUM(t2.amount) <> t1.total_amount
AND SUM(t2.amount) = (t1.component1+t1.component2+t1.component3+t1.component4);
```

It outputs : ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't1.total_amount' in 'having clause'
Needless to say, the field exists in t1 and there were no typos (quadra-checked this, on the brink of insanity here).

---

I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong here. I tried searching SO already and most of the having problems are due to people using HAVING instead of WHERE, but seeing as I'm using SUM(), I think this is the right way to go.

---

EDIT: Terje's answer was the most accurate, although I did manage to pull it off without using that syntax in (possibly the most stupid update sentence of all time) my update sentence, which was (stupid, do not try this at home unless everything else fails):

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.total_amount = 
(
  SELECT SUM(t2.amount) 
  FROM table 2
  --WHERE, AND 
  GROUP BY t1.id
  HAVING SUM(t2.amount) <> t1.total_amount
  AND SUM(t2.amount) = (t1.component1+t1.component2+t1.component3+t1.component4)
)
WHERE t1.id IN (same awful subquery as before, except selecting t2.t1_id)
--AND other conditions
;
```

P.S. : The end goal here is to use the same having conditions in an update sentence
Bunch of thanks in advance,
-Lauri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to compare to `t1.total_amount` you will have to add it to the `GROUP BY`clause, or to compare to e.g. `min(total_amount)`. As you are grouping by `t1.id` it does not matter what aggregate function of total_amount you are using.

Comment: Hmm, this idea might actually be better for my end solution. Thanks, Terje! When I get it to work in the update, Your answer shall be selected.

Answer (score -1):

`HAVING` and `GROUP BY` only works on things you are actually selecting, unlike the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses.  So you need to select `total_amount`, I'm afraid.  <del>Also, the syntax is '!=' for unequal in MySQL.</del> (I stand corrected, '<>' is fine in MySQL.)

Think of `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` as your manipulation of the tables you are selecting from, and `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` as manipulating the data you now have.

Comment: Okay, selecting the field seems to have done the trick, except now I get an empty set, where I should be getting results. This might be on my end though, I'll get back to you on that. Thanks for the idea, Svip. Word of note though, <> works just fine ;).

Comment: Oh.  Well, I'll remove that note from the answer then.

Comment: Yep, empty sets were due to my own stupidity. I don't know why anyone would -1 your answer though, as you were first and mostly on point.

Comment: Maybe someone is jealous.  But that is how `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` works.  Regardless, I am glad to help.

Comment: @swip Your answer still contains errors: You can `group by` fields that you don't select, and `order by` is done after `group by`and `having`. The -1 was not mine, though.

Comment: I do see why this was downvoted now - Your answer orders me to select fields that I do not need. This is never ideal and would ruin any chances of update.